# How can i strip the spaces with proper format?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, strip

I have below strings as-

1. ```
                                                                Meli Rif (                         kin.meli@gc.com                         ), Attorney, Regulatory Affairs Division, General Counsel, Pension Benefit Guaranty Corporation.
   ```
2. ```
                                                              Carol, Program Analyst, by telephone at; or by email at                          Carlomn@a.com.
   ```

I used the below code as -

```
df['strings'].strip()
```

But it returns the output as -
1.Meli Rif (kin.meli@gc.com), Attorney, Regulatory Affairs Division, General Counsel, Pension Benefit Guaranty Corporation

2.Carol, Program Analyst, by telephone at; or by email atCarolmn@a.com.

In the second string its striping all the spaces => email atCarolmn@a.com

How can i get space before striping  ---- want this to be ---- email at Carolmn@a.com

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.replace`:

```
df['string'] = df['string'].str.replace(r'\s\s+', ' ', regex=True)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien  , TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments. getting error? I have this string as a string like I am using itertext of XML and putting into a variable.

Comment: Working now when used - ' '.join(string.split()).

Comment: How do you apply this on your column?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien  - its a string not a dataframe column so i used it as , result =  '  '.join(text.split())  .